# scripts to automatically manage imports or refactor modules

Tags: haskell, refactoring

Does anyone know of tools to manage Haskell imports? Sometimes, I want to refactor things by moving them to another file, and a script to generate the minimal set of imports [for the new file] would be nice.

Comment: I know there is a fair amount of work going on right now for the Eclipse plugin for Haskell. I would hope this is planned, though I don't know if it's happening anytime soon. Google "EclipseFP"...

Comment: You mean something like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXHSiUPKLvg ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GHC can tell you which imports are required; simply add the `-fwarn-unused-imports` flag.

Answer (score 5):

There's a program called [fix-imports](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fix-imports) that can generate a minimal set of imports for you. It only works for qualified imports, though.