# Check if import is redundant

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to parse `haskell` source and for given import check if it is redundant?

[`haskell-src`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src) should be useful, but I've found nothing similar here.

Comment: Do you want to check which imports are unnecessary in the Haskell files that you compile?  GHC does this.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6756477/507803

Comment: No, running `ghc` and parsing the output is the last thing that could be a solution here.

Comment: `hlint` can do exactly that.

Comment: `ghc -ddump-minimal-imports`?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson hlint can do that for all file, not for specific import.

Comment: "No, running ghc and parsing the output is the last thing that could be a solution here." Is this a sarcastic comment?

Comment: hlint does this and if you're using vim, you can use the syntastic plugin with ghc-mod and it'll automatically highlight import lines that are redundant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice new package called [module-management](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/module-management-0.15.1) that has the functionality you need. It has a [cleanImports](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/module-management/0.15.1/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Modules-Imports.html) function that does exactly what it sounds like. It also has a bunch of other facilities for managing modules that may be useful.

The main problem I see--not having used the package myself--is that the `cleanImports` function does quite a bit all at once. If you want functions at a higher granularity, you will either have to look through other parts of the package or maybe even factor out some basic functionality yourself. That said, I think this package is the perfect place to start.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at this package, but it [seems to be too experimental](https://gist.github.com/dmalikov/6098556).

Comment: Hah, yeah. I believe it was released very recently--there was a haskell-cafe topic about it just a little while ago.

Answer (score 0):

[fix-imports](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fix-imports) is pretty great if you want something a bit simpler than module-management (which I haven't tried, so don't feel qualified to compare beyond what hackage suggests).

Comment: Oh, as Even Laforge said, it only deals with qualified imports.